# Adding background to edittext breaks the layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm try to design an input text view. Here is the code I use.

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="7dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="22dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff7171">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The thing I try to achieve is round corners and a little shadow under the layout. Here is the output of this code:

[image]

This gives me 2 disadvantage. First, I can't use floating label with this. This is a low priority. What bugs me is: the underline. I am trying to remove it. The common way people suggest was use:

```
android:background="@null"
```

However, when I use it, the output becomes like this:

[image]

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named background under drawable folder and paste the following codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/background.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#00000000"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then rewrite the autocompletetextview as

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background.xml"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a perfect solution which solves both of my problems. I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentPadding="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff7171"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the result:

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: Thanks. How silly for me I missed that simple solution.